# How to skip before_save when timestamps changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

How to skip triggering `before_save` callback when timestamps has been changed?

I tried

```
def before_save_callback
  unless created_at_changed?
    # do somethinh
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
before_save :my_method, :unless => :updated_at_changed?
```

created_at will not change unless you manually change it. I recommend manually updating updated_at and then using code above.